# Custom ActionBar, Preserving the Menu Button on Tablets

Tags: android, customization, android-actionbar

I'd like to use a completely custom action bar (with my own text, font and background), but to the right I would like to preserve the standard menu icon that appears on tablets and devices that don't have a hardware menu button (e.g. Samsung Galaxy).

Basically I would like to have this for tablets:

[image: tablets]

And this for regular phones that support the hardware menu button:

[image: phones]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question is "how to do this ?", I'd answer that you should use style.

See this [page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html).

Comment: Unfortuately, this does not quite answer my question. The page only describes how to style an existing ActionBar. Not how to check if a menu button should be visible or not (if it's a tablet or not).

Comment: If you just customize the ActionBar, its behaviour will be kept and the menu icon will appear only if needed.